# correlation using pandas and plot

Tags: python, pandas

```
    geneid  fdr_new fdr_old
gene1   4.66E-05    1.45E-05
gene2   0.059650791 0.043799129
gene3   0.04405402  0.061581326
gene4   0.032286852 0.088522898
gene5   0.025672937 0.004911527
gene6   0.001094006 0.000229285
gene7   0.098444488 0.002132802
gene8   0.006079767 0.000230392
gene9   0.000117813 0.000894136
gene10  0.004925041 0.002640812
gene11  0.00036314  5.46E-05
gene12  0.026337682 0.018557193
gene13  0.001503366 0.004951799
gene14  3.05E-05    4.37E-06
gene15  0.001006888 0.009248765
gene16  8.11E-05    0.006124903
gene17  0.062408836 0.026734781
gene18  0.09637641  0.097559967
gene19  0.00405273  0.075971307
gene20  0.078261356 0.080722817
gene21  0.033206859 0.019133673
gene22  0.029851363 0.037940196
```

How can i correlate fdr_old with fdr_new using pandas and get a plot like this [image]

thanks

EDIT:

or something like this.
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

like this?

```
In [45]: import seaborn as sns

In [46]: sns.lmplot(x='fdr_old', y='fdr_new', data=df)
Out[46]: <seaborn.axisgrid.FacetGrid at 0xbb8b470>
```

Result:

[image]

**UPDATE:** correlation between two columns:

```
In [47]: df.filter(like='fdr').corr()
Out[47]:
          fdr_new   fdr_old
fdr_new  1.000000  0.551083
fdr_old  0.551083  1.000000
```

Comment: what is the difference between linear regression and correlation

Comment: @novicebioinforesearcher, please check [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2125/whats-the-difference-between-correlation-and-simple-linear-regression)

Comment: so in other words I cannot correlate one column vs one column is that true?

Comment: @novicebioinforesearcher, actually you can - check updated answer. But we don't know what do you want to achieve

Comment: I want to see what is the the degree of difference in between fdr(false discovery rate) of two columns for each gene, these fdr were generated from two different approaches, i was hoping to see if the fdr's fall close to each other.

Comment: the link was useful, I tried to emulate the lmplot on jupyter notebook i cannot see  the plot can only see this command `<seaborn.axisgrid.FacetGrid at 0x117ba4cd0>` is there another command to see plot inplace?

Comment: found it need to enter this to get plot inline `%matplotlib inline`

Comment: @novicebioinforesearcher, you need to run magic command: `%matplotlib` in jupyter notebook

Comment: is it wrong if i say this I need to plot corelation between fdr_old and fdr_new for each gene(row) and plot it?

Comment: can someone please help me with my last question

Comment: @novicebioinforesearcher, can you explain how do you imagine it? What about plotting a difference `fdr_new - fdr_old` (Y axis) for each `gene` (X axis)?

Comment: I have added a new figure where each point is i believe a point representing each data point and the correlation.

Comment: @novicebioinforesearcher, i would suggest you to try different seaborn plots. You can start [here](http://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/). [Pandas visualisation docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html)

Comment: thanks, may be I need to ask my question in a better way. But I understood what your saying.

Comment: I guess I cannot from the [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/157077/is-it-possible-to-compute-a-correlation-between-two-variables-from-just-means-s) it looks like i cannot